# Auto Exit and Build Success Message Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I am using webpack 4 for creating build for React Application , build is happening correctly however we have decided to use CI/CD for automating build process , so in there we are facing issue in which npm run build is correctly doing build but does not exit with some kind of success message so that build tool come to know about success or failure

How to make success and failure workflow in webpack , please help

Comment: What automation CI/CD you want to use. I believe that Webpack should by default exit with error code if something has failed.

Comment: Jenkins,,, fine for failure but not exiting in case of success, normally i have to do ctrl + c  manually